# not getting ajax response from server side file

Tags: php, ajax

as u can see below I am trying to change part o f my page without reload all page using ajax but I am not gettign any response

I am working on local host xampp and both files are in same directory

I also tired to palce files on host and nothing happen 
i did not get even an error while connecting to the database in the **accdata.php** file when I place them on server while there is no database

I trid a lost to change the way of ponting the url part of xmlhttp.open

like file:///C:/xml/dineshkani.xml

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Site Title</title>

</head>

<body align="left">

<div>
    <h4 align="left">Balance Enquiry</h4>
</div>

<form>
     <div>
        <label>Account Number </label>
        <input id="AccNum" type="text" name="AccNumInput">
        <button type="button" onclick="SendForm()">Search</button>
      </div>
</form>

<script>
function SendForm()
{
    alert("Hello! SendForm start");
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {

                document.getElementById("AccNum").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    };
        alert("Hello! going to send ajax");
        xmlhttp.open("POST","AccData.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send(document.getElementById("AccNum").value);  // you want to pass the Value so u need the .value at the end!!!

        alert(document.getElementById("AccNum").value);
        alert("Hello! SendForm end");
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**accdata.php**

```
<?php

alert("Hello! php start processing");
echo "start";

$AccountNumber = $_POST['AccNum'];

$conn = oci_connect('admin', 'admin', 'localhost/JDT', 'AL32UTF8');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

alert("Hello! connected to oracle");

$sqlstr = 'SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,CUST_NAME,PHONE1 FROM customers where CUSTOMER_ID=:AccNum';

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sqlstr); // creates the statement

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':AccNum', $AccountNumber); // binds the parameter

oci_execute($stid); // executes the query

echo $AccountNumber;
/**
 *  THIS WHILE LOOP CREATES ALL OF YOUR HTML (its no good solution to echo data out like this)
 */
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td align=center>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid); // releases the statement
oci_close($conn); // closes the conneciton

?>
```

Comment: the `alert` statements in the php file will not do what you expect and the ajax function just sends a value rather than a name:value pair

Comment: i had add the alert message just to check if the first page reach to second page as break point it is not part of code

Answer (score 0):

The ajax function is only sending a value rather than a post variable with associated value. Try along these lines - tidied it up a little but the important bit is the `name=value` in the parameters send via ajax and setting the `Content-Type` header often helps with stubborn xhr requests.

The javascript needn't be in the body - hence I moved that to the head section of the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Site Title</title>
        <script>
            function SendForm(){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        document.getElementById("AccNum").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open( "POST", "AccData.php", true );
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xmlhttp.send( 'AccNum='+document.getElementById("AccNum").value );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4 align="left">Balance Enquiry</h4>
        </div>
        <form>
             <div>
                <label>Account Number </label>
                <input id="AccNum" type="text" name="AccNumInput">
                <button type="button" onclick="SendForm()">Search</button>
              </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

A basic ajax function which can be re-used merely changing the parameters when it gets called.

```
function ajax(method,url,parameters,callback){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )callback.call( this, xhr.response );
    };

    var params=[];
    for( var n in parameters )params.push( n+'='+parameters[n] );

    switch( method.toLowerCase() ){
        case 'post':
            var p=params.join('&');
        break;
        case 'get':
            url+='?'+params.join('&');
            var p=null;
        break;  
    }
    xhr.open( method.toUpperCase(), url, true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send( p );
}

function cbaccdata(r){ document.getElementById('AccNum').innerHTML=r; }


function sendForm(){
    ajax.call( this, 'post','accdata.php',{ 'AccNum':document.getElementById("AccNum").value },cbaccdata );
}
```

Comment: same same after I made modification you suggest nothing happen when I press the search button I tried to add alert("Hello"); to the beginning of function send to check if the code is reach that point and message not displayed 
   function sendForm()
   {
    alert("Hello");
    ajax.call( this, 'post','accdata.php',{ 'AccNum':document.getElementById("AccNum").value },cbaccdata );
   }